# conditional filtering in SPSS

Tags: spss

I create a number of reports for different constituencies using an SPSS macro. One of these groups only wants data from female respondents, but the rest want both male and female respondents in the data. Is it possible to create a conditional filter in SPSS so that I can use the same loop for all of the reports, or do I have to create a separate syntax for the group that only wants females?

Edit: An abridged version of my code looks like this:

```
DEFINE !ess1 (inum=!charend ('/') 
/ iname=!charend ('/')
/ iname2=!charend ('/')
/ g1=!charend ('/')
/ g2=!charend ('/')
/ g3=!charend ('/')
/ g4=!charend ('/')).

RECODE INST 
    (!inum=1) 
    ( !g1 = 2) 
    (!g2= 3)    
    (!g3=4)
    (!g4=5)
    into cgroup.
MISSING VALUES cgroup(-9).
variable labels cgroup 'Comparison Group'.
value labels cgroup 1 !iname2 2 'Thing1' 3 'Thing2' 4 'Thing3' 5 'Thing4'.
EXECUTE.

USE ALL.
VARIABLE LEVEL ALL (NOMINAL).

CTABLES
  /VLABELS VARIABLES=satisf cgroup DISPLAY=DEFAULT
  /TABLE cgroup  [ROWPCT.COUNT PCT40.1] BY satisf
  /SLABELS VISIBLE=NO
  /CATEGORIES VARIABLES=satisf cgroup ORDER=A KEY=VALUE EMPTY=INCLUDE TOTAL=YES LABEL="Overall" POSITION=AFTER
  MISSING=EXCLUDE
  /TITLES
   TITLE= 'Overall, how satisfied have you been with this example syntax?'.

DELETE VARIABLES cgroup.

OUTPUT EXPORT
  /CONTENTS  EXPORT=VISIBLE  LAYERS=PRINTSETTING  MODELVIEWS=PRINTSETTING
  /PDF  DOCUMENTFILE=!Quote(!Concat('filepath',!iname,'.pdf'))
     EMBEDBOOKMARKS=YES  EMBEDFONTS=YES.

OUTPUT SAVE
OUTFILE=!Quote(!Concat('filepath',!iname,'.spv'))

OUTPUT CLOSE *. 
OUTPUT NEW.

!ENDDEFINE.

!ess1 inum=1/iname=Name1/ iname2='Name1'/g1= 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 /g2= 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29/g3=31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38/g4=41,42,43,44,45/.
!ess1 inum=2 /iname=Name2 /iname2='Name2'/g1= 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 /g2= 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29/g3=31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38/g4=41,42,43,44,45/.
!ess1 inum=3 /iname=Name3 /iname2='Name3'/g1= 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 /g2= 21,22,23,24,25,26,27,29/g3=31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38/g4=41,42,43,44,45/.
```

Comment: The answer is probably yes, but it depends of what you have done so far. please post your code of the macro (loop).

Comment: Thanks for responding to both of my questions mirirai! My loops are over 1000 lines long, so in the edit I did above, I took out all but an example table... Let me know if there is more information I should put in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how you have setup this workflow, you could temporarily set the `INST` variable to `SYSMIS` for the particular Institutions(?) where you want to exclude males.

So adding something like this below to your code:

```
/* Untested */.
TEMP.
DO IF ANY(INST, !g1).
  RECODE INST (ELSE=SYSMIS).
END IF.
CTABLES ...
```

With `INST` variable now set to `SYSMIS`, `CTABLES` shall by default exclude these cases in any tabular presentation of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a parameter to the macro for whether to filter out males and then, conditional on that being yes (!IF !femalesonly eq "yes"), generate the appropriate compute and filter syntax (and then turn it off at the end).

Comment: Thanks for answering JKP. Can you give me an example of what this would look like? I'm still new to using macros in SPSS.